# How to remove version number from war file

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-war-plugin, maven-ear-plugin

I have a Dependency in child pom like this.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sample-groupID</groupId>
            <artifactId>sfint</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>  
            <type>war</type>                
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And I am using maven-ear-plugin.

```
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven.ear.plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
            <modules>
                <webModule>
                    <groupId>sample-gropuID</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sfint</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <moduleID>WebModule_sfint</moduleID>
                    <bundleFileName>sfint.war</bundleFileName>  
                </webModule>
            </modules>  
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Now my problem is that I want my war file to be like this - **sfint.war** but I am getting it as - **sfint.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war**

Any help ??

Comment: You should try to use  `sfint` only...If this does not work it would be a good idea to file in a [Issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MEAR)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Within the `<build>` tag specify the name that you need for the artifact as "finalName".

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>`

Answer (score 2):

You can configure [maven-ear-plugin to omit the version information](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customize-file-name-mapping.html) in the EAR file:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
           [...]
           <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Does not work. Still getting the snapshot version in my war file.

Comment: This will remove all versions including those from other dependencies, which is not always desirable.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `outputFileNameMapping` option for the `maven-ear-plugin` plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@@{dashClassifier?}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myEAR</groupId>
  <artifactId>myEAR</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <configuration>
          <earSourceDirectory>EarContent</earSourceDirectory>
          <generateApplicationXml>false</generateApplicationXml>
          <version>6</version>
          <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
          <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>myWAR</groupId>
        <artifactId>myWAR</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

your final EAR will be myEAR-0.0.1.SNAPSHOT.EAR that contains myWAR.war (without version number)
if you want to remove version number from EAR also than add myEar

Answer (score 0):

If the war/ejb is part of an ear project, one should use bundleFileName to change the module names in the final ear artifact.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${version.ear.plugin}</version>
   <configuration>
     <modules>
       <webModule>
         <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
         <artifactId>myapp-web</artifactId>
         <contextRoot>/myapp</contextRoot>
         <bundleFileName>myapp-web.war</bundleFileName>
       </webModule>
       <ejbModule>
         <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
         <artifactId>myapp-ejb</artifactId>
         <bundleFileName>myapp-ejb.jar</bundleFileName>
       </ejbModule>
     </modules>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```