# How to remove project version from .war file

Tags: java, maven, war, ear

I want to generate two artifacts (.ear) for one profile with two maven builds. I need that the name of the artifact doesn't contain the project version,  I can't do it this way.

I'm trying multiple solutions but none has served to me.
I tried to include the tag `<outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>`
or the tag 
`<fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>`
to the configuration tag.
I tried to change the maven-ear-plugin version too, with the same result.

This is my configuration:

```
<finalName>${area}${project.parent.artifactId}</finalName>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>ear-prepro</id>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.parent.artifactId}finalll</finalName>
                <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
                <earSourceDirectory>src/main/resources</earSourceDirectory>
                <displayName>${area}${artifactId}</displayName>
                <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.parent.artifactId}-web</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>${project.parent.artifactId}-web.war</bundleFileName>
                        <contextRoot>/${project.parent.artifactId}</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>ear</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

--------------------------
AND THE OTHER EAR CONFIGURATION
----------------------------

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>ear-protest</id>
            <configuration>
                <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                <finalName>${area}${project.parent.artifactId}-PROTEST</finalName>
                <earSourceDirectory>src/main/resources</earSourceDirectory>
                <displayName>${area}${artifactId}-PROTEST</displayName>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/PROTEST</outputDirectory>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.parent.artifactId}-web</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>${project.parent.artifactId}-web.war</bundleFileName>
                        <contextRoot>/${project.parent.artifactId}</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>ear</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It seems that the tag  concats the version number to the artifact, but I don't need it.  I need the name of the artifact without the project version on the .war file.

Some ideas?

Comment: try the below one may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411621/how-to-remove-version-number-from-war-file

Comment: This changes the name of the .ear, i want to change the name of the .war file.

Comment: Then did you try to configure the maven-war-plugin?

Comment: yes, I configure the maven-war-plugin but it not wokrs too

Comment: The maven-ear-plugin of version 2.8 does not have a parameter `<outputFileNameMapping>..</outputFileNameMapping>` you should use the most recent version otherwise this will never work...